# Remove orphaned key/value from rails store hash

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I'm using a text column and rails' store to record user preferences like so:

```
class User

  store :prefs, accessors: [:dismiss_setup, :initiate_setup]

  after_initialize :set_defaults

  private

    def set_defaults
      self.dismiss_setup ||= false
      self.initiate_setup || = false
    end

end
```

This, of course, looks like this:

```
#<User id: 13, prefs: {"dismiss_setup"=>false, "initiate_setup"=>"false"} ...
```

During development I have changed these accessors several times as workflows improve. I can't figure out how to automatically purge them from the prefs hash. I'm ending up with a lot of key/values that are now deprecated like this:

```
#<User id: 13, prefs: {"dismiss_setup"=>false, "initiate_setup"=>"false", "something_old"=>"true", "no_longer_used"=>"true"} ...
```

I want to make changes in the future without cluttering up the Users table. Is there a way to compare the prefs hash with my current store accessors and delete any that don't exist? Or perhaps another way to look at the problem?

Answer (score 0):

Here's what I came up with:

```
class User

  store :prefs, accessors: [:dismiss_setup, :initiate_setup]

  after_initialize :clean_up, :set_defaults

  def array_of_prefs
    self.class.name.constantize.stored_attributes[:prefs]
  end

  private

    def clean_up
      a = self.array_of_prefs.map &:to_s
      self.prefs.keep_if { |k,v| a.include? k }
    end

    def set_defaults
      self.dismiss_setup ||= false
      self.initiate_setup ||= false
    end

end
```

As a bonus, @user.array_of_prefs can be merged in with other strong parameters in the users controller. Keeps everything dynamic.